# How to update Query to calc SUM or COUNT using two dates and BETWEEN?

Tags: mysql, sql

My current query is as such:

```
     SELECT
      CAST(COUNT(`MID`) AS UNSIGNED) AS Y,
      CONCAT(
          LEFT(MONTHNAME(`date`),
          3),
          ' ',
          YEAR(`date`)
      ) AS label
  FROM
      `reservations`
  WHERE
      `MID` = 22 AND YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE())
  GROUP BY
      CONCAT(
          LEFT(MONTHNAME(DATE),
          3),
          ' ',
          YEAR(`date`)
      ),
      YEAR(DATE),
      MONTH(DATE)
  ORDER BY
      YEAR(`date`),
      MONTH(`date`) ASC
```

It produces the following results that we use in Google Charts to show the number of reservations per month. 
The issue is we are only getting the number of times a reservation is created, not the number of days between the start date (date) and the end date (dateLast).

```
 Y      label
 ________________
 22      Feb 2019
 28      Mar 2019
 15      Apr 2019
 3       May 2019
 5       Jun 2019
 2       Jul 2019
 1       Aug 2019
 1       Oct 2019
 2       Nov 2019
 9       Dec 2019
```

I've been trying the following update but getting an error related to the BETWEEN operator:

```
 SELECT
     CAST(COUNT(`mid`) AS UNSIGNED BETWEEN `date` AND `dateLast`) AS D, CONCAT(
         LEFT(MONTHNAME(DATE),
         3), ' ',  YEAR(DATE) ),
     CAST(COUNT(`mid`) AS UNSIGNED) AS Y,
     CONCAT(
         LEFT(MONTHNAME(DATE),
         3),
         ' ',
         YEAR(DATE)
     ) AS label
 FROM
     `reservations`
 WHERE
     `mid` = 22 AND YEAR(DATE) = YEAR(CURDATE())
 GROUP BY
     CONCAT(
         LEFT(MONTHNAME(DATE),
         3),
         ' ',
         YEAR(DATE)
     ),
     YEAR(DATE),
     MONTH(DATE)
 ORDER BY
     YEAR(DATE),
     MONTH(DATE) ASC
```

## MySQL said: Documentation

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN `date` AND `dateLast`) AS D, CONCAT(LEFT(MONTHNAME(DATE),' at line 2

The goal is to get a SUM for all days reserved between AND including `date` to `dateLast`   Note: `dateLast` is not counted as it is the Checkout date. Maybe this is too complex for a SQL query and should be handled in PHP as a series of sub-routines?

Comment: Can a reservation go over three (or more) months like "from 2019-01-15 to 2019-03-15"?

Comment: Generally, they are only a week (7) days or so. But we are trying to count instances so if we had a date-range from 2019-01-28 to 2019-02-4 we would have split the instances between those two months. But we would be happy even if the start date (`date') was bound to an overlap (meaning all day instances are forced into the initial month) we would still be happy with those results.

Comment: If you don't need to split the number over two months, then just use `SUM(DATEDIFF(dateLast, date))`?

Comment: Check your data: `select * from reservations where dateLast <= date`

Comment: Yup, there were some extreme selections made spanning into next year from this year... Also wrapping SUM in the ABS function removed the minus symbols

Comment: There should be no negative numbers if your data is not "corrupted". `datediff('2020-01-05', '2019-12-25')` works just fine. I would fix the data rather than using `ABS()` and return good looking but wrong results.

Comment: I agree... Problem was I expected the first date would come before the second in comparison. DATEDIFF works in reverse of what I thought, and now correcting that (and the bad data) makes everything look as it should without ABS().     SUM(DATEDIFF(`dateLast`,`date`))

Comment: Yes, DATEDIFF is confusing for our brains. We think it would be correct to write `DIFF(10, 30)` - But it rather works like `SUB(30, 10)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to split the number of days of one reservation over multiple months, then you can just use SUM(DATEDIFF(dateLast, date))

```
select year(date) y, month(date) m, sum(datediff(dateLast, date)) c
from reservations
group by y, m
order by y, m
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hBj4CuU2ia3cScmHHr2LKZ/0)

If you want to split them, then I hope your version (MySQL 8+ or MariaDB 10.2+) supports recursive queries. In that case you can expand the date range to one row per day in the range and count them:

```
with recursive rcte as (
  select date, dateLast 
  from reservations
  where dateLast > date -- optional
  union all
  select rcte.date + interval 1 day, rcte.dateLast
  from rcte
  where rcte.date < rcte.dateLast - interval 1 day
)
  select year(date) y, month(date) m, count(*) c
  from rcte
  group by y,m
  order by y,m
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/omCqZZ2nGRZD9PKhHWkC8h/0)

Answer (score 1):

SQL can definitely handle this. Use the DATEDIFF function
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_datediff.asp